# javascript obtain value of select option without submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I'm trying to get the value of input select option without submitting the form (need to keep it available while displaying the live results).  I then need to use this value with a global variable to be inserted in an array later on.  Because I can't use submit, I need to find a way to update this value if the user changes the option (ie probably using onchange).

Here's what I have currently (doesn't work):

**html**

```
<select id="color" >
    <option value="">select:</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

**javascript**

```
document.getElementById('color').onchange = function() {
    var colorInput = this.value;
    console.log(colorInput);
};
```

**updated**

Okay, no using inline javascript, I get it.  I updated the script above to reflect most of the answers I'm getting - which are not addressing my central problem.  Tracking the input option value within the script is no problem; I need to the value as a global variable.  For some reason I can't do it.

Here's a jsfiddle that is analogous to how I need to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/agvRn/2/

It should be able to track the select option (already can) and then must be able to use this value in a separate function - in this case inserting it into the paragraph field "show".

Answer (score 2):

Don't use inline JavaScript.

Try this (avoiding global variables):

```
(function() {
    var select_val;
    document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function() {
        select_val = this.value;
        document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = select_val;
    }, false);

})();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/agvRn/3/)

Comment: @user3180105, just for clarification, the function is wrapped in what's called a "closure", making it so `select_val` can only be accessed inside the closure. This lets you have more control over the global namespace.

Comment: this is a much cleaner solutions, my answer was just a way to solve your problem. you would be much better off digesting this solution and leveraging the pattern in the futre

Comment: My whole issue was that I need to use this input option as a global variable - "colorInput".

Comment: @user3180105 You need to move it inside the onchange handler it should work. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would suggest you don't use the inline `onchange` attribute.

You can try this (see the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agvRn/)):

```
document.getElementById('color').onchange = function() {
    var color = this.value;

    console.log(color);
};
```

Better yet, use `addEventListener`:

```
document.getElementById('color').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var color = this.value;

    console.log(color);
});
```

Comment: aside from not using the inline js, I already had this functionality.  The whole problem is that I can't access the value outside of the onchange script.

Answer (score 0):

you may try

```
var  colorInput;    
function colorCalc(value) {
    colorInput = value;
    console.log(colorInput);
}
```

i think the issue is that you are trying to set the var from the method return but at the time you call the method you are not giving it a value

instead you should let the method set you value when the change event triggers it with the selected value

```
function colorCalc(value) {
    return value;
}
var colorInput = colorCalc(/*there is no value here value == undefined so will return undefined*/);
console.log(colorInput);
```